# Getting back argument from a function called from a command method Tkinter Python

Tags: python, methods, tkinter, return-value

I'm trying to get values from a function when I press a menubar but I don't know how to do:

Let's say that I have the next function:

```
def other1():
    return 10
def other2(a):
    print(a)
Insert = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
x=Insert.add_command(label="InsertA1", command=other1)
Insert.add_command(label="InsertA2", command=other2(x))
```

And when I tried to press the InsertA2 menubar it's just given me 'None' values ...
Any help?

Comment: What do you mean get the value? Use the somewhere else in the code? Printing it? Displaying it in a widget?

Comment: I'm trying to get value from a function to print that value in another function

Comment: Save them globally.

Comment: It is still showing me as none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Menu.add_command` doesn't return anything (at least to my knowledge), which is partially why you're getting a None.

When you do `command=other2(x)`, it's actually not doing what you expected, it's actually making `command` equal to the return value of `other2(x)`, since function calls are evaluated at run time. You meant to be doing `command=lambda x=x: other2(x)`.

If you're doing `x=Insert.add_command(...)` to keep a reference to the command so you can use edit it later, that's not how you do it. You can configure the command by `Menu.entryconfigure(index)`, and access its configurations by `Menu.entrycget(index)`, whereas the index is the position/order you add the command entry. http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/menu.htm#M55.